# ASP.NET Client and ASP.NET WCF Server production update overload

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a WCF Server with all the business logic, and a MVC client who get all data, including news and images, from this server.

The problem is when I have to update the server, the constant access the client overloads the server with calls, and it can't go up. In the end all available memory is consumed and the server does not start.

If I stop the client, start the server, then after it is loaded (relatively fast) I start the client, it works fine.

I use ISS with Windows Server 2013, and MVC 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a 'temporary off-line' checker in your app.

If you experience X errors in Y time, wait for a few seconds, and then try again. Increase the waiting time over the number of tries.

In this way, you prevent the server to get overloaded. And your client will resume as soon as the service is ready.

Comment: I hoped for a solution without "disabling" the client, but this work.